# Populate an input field with a string that contains a double quote

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm getting a value back from the server that contains a double quote in it.  I need to populate an input tag with the value.

I've tried using escape(myVariable), but that converts the spaces to %20, etc.
I suppose I could write an if/then that says if there's a double quote in the field, then use value='', but then what do I do if they have both double and single quotes in the field?

Comment: I tried using the html code ```&#34;``` instead of ```"``` as the value (for example: ```value="&#34;language&#34; OR &#34;slang&#34;"```) and was not able to get it to work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
input.value = val.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace double quotes with `&quot;`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting a value back from the
>   server that contains a double quote in
>   it.

You flagged your question as "javascript" so I assume you are loading this server value via ajax.

If the variable containing your value has already been assigned there is no reason to encode anything.

Here is a sample script that takes a variable that has already been assigned and puts it into a new form element.  As you can see, the form element has no problem at all displaying both single and double quotes at the same time.

```
<html>
<body>
<form id='myform'></form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myField = "James' answer is \"the best\"";

var i = document.createElement('input');
i.type = 'text';
i.name = 'testField';
i.value = myField;
document.getElementById('myform').appendChild(i);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: James, I really like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#input").val(unescape('"test " value" "'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Test value: <input type="text"  id="input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Best Solution is Use htmlentities in php language:**

```
<input value="<?php echo htmlentities($value);?>">
```

**Worked in all cases:**

*1) Single Quote*

example: Julia's cat

*2) Double Quote*

example: John"s Bike

Enjoy and Share the code to save other's life :)