# Append HTML with triple quotes in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to construct an HTML string before I append it to an element. Here is the string:

```
var html = '<tr><td data-value="' + someValue + '"></td></tr>';
$(el).append(html);
```

The value in `someValue` is `24"`. There is a `"` in it.

When the HTML is appended the element is wrong. Apparently appending `"24""` makes the element recognize only the `"24"` and there is one loose `"` in the end. How can I do this?

I tried to replace:

```
(someValue.indexOf('"') > 0 ? someValue.replace('"','\"') : someValue)
```

But still the error persists.

Comment: You could either use jQuery methods to add the value as they will escape it for you, eg `attr()` or `data()`, or you could manually HTML encode it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/519413

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate an input field with a string that contains a double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383520/populate-an-input-field-with-a-string-that-contains-a-double-quote)

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM methods (or jQuery abstractions of them) instead of trying to mash strings into valid HTML.

```
var tr = $("<tr />);
var td = $("<td />)
    .attr("data-value', someValue);
tr.append(td);
$(el).append(tr);
```

Comment: For some reason this cannot be applied to my solution. I have thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so according to Quentin's comment. This works:

```
(someValue.indexOf('"') > 0 ? someValue.replace('"','&quot;') : someValue)
```

Thanks!